# Update the display of counting of children according to their state in a React component

Tags: reactjs, tree, render, children

I have a tree structure of components of type A, B, C

I would like my *Component_Type_B* components to be able to display (in a specific field) the number of Component_Type_C that are inside
And the *Component_Type_A* components to display (in a specific field) the total of *Component_Type_C*.

So render function of A would be something like:

```
render {
    return (<div>
        <span>Total of Component_Type_C inside: {...}</span>
        <div>{renderComponentsB}</div>
    </div>)
}
```

render function of B would be something like:

```
render {
    return (<div>
        <span>Total of Component_Type_C inside: {...}</span>
        <div>{renderComponentsC}</div>
    </div>)
}
```

The **constraint** is that I would like to count only the *Component_Type_C* that have two state properties to a certain value:

E.g.:

```
this.state.has_propA = true
this.state.has_propB = true
```

These properties can change at any time being that *Component_Type_C* components are modified by user interactions

```
<Component_Type_A>   => Should display '7'
    <Component_Type_B>    => Should display '4'
        <Component_Type_C />
        <Component_Type_C />
        <Component_Type_C />
        <Component_Type_C />
    </Component_Type_B>
    <Component_Type_B>    => Should display '2'
        <Component_Type_C />
        <Component_Type_C />
    </Component_Type_B>
    <Component_Type_B>    => Should display '1'
        <Component_Type_C />     
        <Component_Type_C />    // this.state.has_propA = true  and   this.state.has_propB = false
        <Component_Type_C />    // this.state.has_propA = true  and   this.state.has_propB = false
    </Component_Type_B>
</Component_Type_A>
```

So, how can I refresh the values displayed at *Component_Type_B* and Component_Type_C level, according to the state of *Component_Type_C's*?

I have a huge list of *Component_Type_C* nested in a multilevel Component_Type_B's, so minimizing render loops is an objective.

Answer (score 0):

hows it going?

Honestly, the simplest solution is to create a nested array in your store.

Every time you create a `ComponentB`, you add an empty array. When you add a C, then you locate the correct array and push a value into the array. Your `ComponentA` will check the store and make the proper checks for length;

```
store = {
  componentStore: [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
}
```

You can structure your store however you would like. I'm sure there may be more efficient ways of storing it.